# Exporting help for multiple emacs lisp symbols into a single Texinfo file

Tags: html, info

I am looking for a way to produce HTML documentation for functions and variables defined in my `.el` files. One way I have seen suggested is by using `texi2html` tool. The challenge is to produce the input for `texi2html`. In particular, how do I export help for multiple Emacs-Lisp symbols into a single Texinfo file?

Answer (score 1):

For racket-mode I wanted to have GitHub host a [`Reference.md`](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/blob/master/Reference.md) file that recapitulated the doc strings for user commands, vars, and faces. That way, people could browse online without installing.

What I came up with to do so is [`racket-make-doc.el`](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/blob/master/racket-make-doc.el). How it works:

1. I specify the commands, vars, and faces in a `defconst` for each.
2. Iterate over each, using (respectively) `(documentation symbol)`, `(documentation-property s 'variable-documentation)`, and `(documentation-property symbol 'face-documentation)`.
3. Do some cleanup and transforms to try to produce valid markdown:

   - Try to "linkify".
   - Adjust `<code>`-ish quotes from `` `docstring' `` to `` `markdown` `` style.
   - HTML escaping.

It's all a bit kludgy but I offer it as-is in case it's a starting point.

Step 3 could instead emit a `.org` or `.texinfo` format file. I suppose it could even emit a `.html` file in the first place.

---

**UPDATE**: More recently, I'm doing almost exactly what I think you want: [these sources](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/tree/master/doc) produce [this HTML](https://www.racket-mode.com).

> ```
>  +-----------------+
>  | racket-mode.org |     +---------------+      ---------------
>  | #!INCLUDE:      |--<--| reference.org |--<--/ generate.el  /---<--{doc strings}
>  +-----------------+     +---------------+     ---------------
>         |
>         |       +------------------+       +------------------+
>         +--->---| racket-mode.texi |--->---| racket-mode.info |
>         |       +------------------+       +------------------+
>         |
>         |       +------------------+
>         +--->---| racket-mode.html |
>                 +------------------+
> ```